# Customizing the Forecast page

Tags: forecast

We are looking to add data to the Forecast page that does not seem to be doable through the standard Forecast setup. Basically the forecasting numbers should be broken down between existing and new customers, as salespeople have quotas for each. So the existing data, which just shows all sales, would need to be broken down as well - new, existing, total. To tell which is which you'd have to look at an Opportunities' account and see if this is the first closed won opp or not. That's not really possible, however (as far as we can tell).

One thought was to duplicate all product listings - one for new customers and one for existing, and group them that way, but it's proven difficult for salespeople to get it right.

We'd like to add custom data to the forecast page based on context (user) but it doesn't look like there is an easy solution. What I had wanted to do was add some JavaScript on the page and, through a combination of DOM manipulation and internal webservices, inject the data appropriately. However, to add JavaScript I usually use sidebar components, which are not on the Forecasts page.

We then tried to pull the Forecasting page in to a custom VisualForce page where we could use JavaScript but couldn't seem to get that to work. One main sticking point was that SFDC likes to put parts of your org on different domains, and Forecasts and custom VisualForce happen to be on different domains so there are cross server scripting issues.

Right now we are down to "rewrite the entire Forecasts section in VisualForce" which would mean building it all ourselves to add about 1% functionality, or creating a greasemonkey/user script and having users that need the extra functionality install it to their browser. Neither are that attractive.

Comment: Can't think of a good alternative to either of those, unfortunately. Unless there is some non-sidebar-component way of injecting JS to the Forecasts page, but I'm not aware of one. Maybe if there is a free AppExchange forecast solution that is close to what you want, you could persuade them to share source?

Comment: I agree, can't think of an alternative ideal solution

Comment: We had to do that for a customer. Once you de cide to go down that route, it can be very rewarding if their Forecast is very specific (wa, in our case).  One major issue is always the number of displayed records, page length and VF view state size.

Comment: We have exactly the same requirement and decided to split all products up into 3 (acquisition, retention, churn). It has gotten really ugly to maintain this. Did any of you come up with an alternative?